# Last modified date of php pages on the server

Tags: php

I am on a linux server with shared hosting. All php pages when accessed by a meta analyser or remote host (Using CURL) shows a very old last modified date.

Please check this link https://www.canvasdesign.co.uk/test1.php

Last modified date when accessed from Meta Analyser or remote host:
2009-08-30 18:00:00
Actual last modified date:
2015-03-04 09:33:23

What is the issue? How can I get the last modified date to be displayed as current date?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Open the file, make a change and save it?

Comment: How are you checking it, some code will help

Comment: In the control panel/file manager it shows latest date. But not when accessed from CURL or meta tag analyser.